# EasyHook is not intercepting any recv calls

Tags: c#, easyhook

I have been trying to hook calls to 'recv' from Chrome and Firefox using EasyHook. However, this isn't working - it does not fail with any errors, but also no packets are being caught. I have tried the example program with 'CreateFile' hooks, and that works perfectly fine...
Since there is next to no documentation on this, I am having trouble fixing this. Here is my code:

```
// the injected library
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using EasyHook;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SocketMon
{
    public class Injection : EasyHook.IEntryPoint
    {
        SocketMonInterface Interface;
        LocalHook CreateFileHook;
        Stack<String> Queue = new Stack<String>();

        public Injection(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InChannelName)
        {
            // connect to host...
            Interface =
             RemoteHooking.IpcConnectClient<SocketMonInterface>(InChannelName);

            // validate connection...
            Interface.Ping();
        }


        public void Run(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext, String InChannelName)
        {
            // install hook...
            try
            {
                CreateFileHook = LocalHook.Create(
                    LocalHook.GetProcAddress("Ws2_32.dll", "recv"),
                    new Drecv(recv_Hooked),
                    this);

                CreateFileHook.ThreadACL.SetInclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
            }
            catch (Exception ExtInfo)
            {
                Interface.ReportException(ExtInfo);

                return;
            }

            Interface.IsInstalled(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId());

            // wait for host process termination...
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);

                    if (Queue.Count > 0)
                    {
                        String[] Package = null;


                        MessageBox.Show(Queue.Count.ToString());
                        lock (Queue)
                        {
                            Package = Queue.ToArray();

                            Queue.Clear();
                        }


                        Interface.OnRecvData(RemoteHooking.GetCurrentProcessId(), Package);
                    }
                    else
                        Interface.Ping();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // NET Remoting will raise an exception if host is unreachable
            }
        }

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,
            CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
            SetLastError = true)]


        delegate int Drecv(
                    IntPtr socketHandle,
                    IntPtr buf,
                    int count,
                    int socketFlags
            );

        // just use a P-Invoke implementation to get native API access
        // from C# (this step is not necessary for C++.NET)
        [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll")]
        static extern int recv(
                    IntPtr socketHandle,
                    IntPtr buf,
                    int count,
                    int socketFlags
            );


        public int recv_Hooked(
                    IntPtr socketHandle,
                    IntPtr buf,
                    int count,
                    int socketFlags
            )
        {
            int len = recv(socketHandle, buf, count, socketFlags);
            Queue.Push(String.Format("Received {0} bytes of data on socket {1}", socketHandle, count));
            return len;
        }
    }
}
```

*

```
//the ipc interface
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SocketMon
{
    public class SocketMonInterface : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void IsInstalled(Int32 InClientPID)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketMon has been installed in target {0}.\r\n", InClientPID);
        }

        public void OnRecvData(Int32 InClientPID, String[] InSocketData)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < InSocketData.Length; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(InSocketData[i]);
            }
        }

        public void ReportException(Exception InInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The target process has reported" +
                              " an error:\r\n" + InInfo.ToString());
        }

        public void Ping()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got pinged");
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried changing SetExclusiveACL to SetInclusiveACL, and that has not helped...

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in your hook method and attach to the process? Is something intercepted?

Comment: Also, can you show your main method/class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised that my code was actually working...

Manually calling 'recv' using P/Invoke worked...

The problem is that Chrome and Firefox did not use 'recv' - when I used SpyStudio to hook them, they actually called other methods in 'wininet.dll,' not using winsocks